# Realizing Top Level Entity in Testbench using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, simulation, test-bench

I'm a newbie in VHDL and hardware world.
I'm trying to make a Count&Compare example using Top Level Hierarchy and test it with testbench and see the results on ISIM.

Here is my block diagram sketch:
[image: Sketch]

So I end up these 3 vhd source files:

**Counter.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Count_src is
    Port ( CLK   : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           S     : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end Count_src;

architecture Behavioral of Count_src is
signal count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

begin
process (Reset, CLK)
    begin
        if Reset = '1' then                             -- Active high reset
            count <= "0000";                            -- Clear count to 0
        elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then                   -- Positive edge
            count <= count + "0001";                    -- increment count
        end if;
    end process;
S <= count;                                             -- Export count
end Behavioral;
```

**Compare**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity Compare_src is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           S : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Compare_src;

architecture Behavioral of Compare_src is

begin

    S <= '1' when (A = B) else          -- Test if A and B are same
         '0';                           -- Set when S is different

end Behavioral;
```

**CountCompare (Top Level)**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity CountCompare_src is
    Port ( Clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Value : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Flag : out  STD_LOGIC);
end CountCompare_src;

architecture Behavioral of CountCompare_src is

-- COMPONENT DECLERATIONS
component counter is
    port ( CLK   : in std_logic;
           Reset : in std_logic;
           S     : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
         );
end component;

component compare is
    port (A : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
          B : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
          S : out std_logic
         );
end component;

-- Component Spesification and Binding
for all : counter use entity work.Count_src(behavioral);
for all : compare use entity work.Compare_src(behavioral);

-- Internal Wires
signal count_out : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin

-- Component instantiation

C1: counter PORT MAP ( Reset => Reset,
                       CLK => Clock,
                       S => count_out
                     );

C2: compare PORT MAP ( A => count_out,
                       B => Value,
                       S => Flag
                     );

end Behavioral;
```

To test the design I wrote a testbench as follows:

**TestBench**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY TopLevelTester_tb IS
END TopLevelTester_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF TopLevelTester_tb IS 

   --Input and Output definitions.
   signal Clock : std_logic := '0';
    signal Reset : std_logic := '0';
   signal Value : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1000";
    signal Flag  : std_logic;

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 1 ns;

BEGIN

   -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: entity work.CountCompare_src PORT MAP 
    (
        Clock => Clock,
        Reset => Reset,
        Value => Value
    );

   proc: process
   begin
       Clock <= '0';
       wait for clk_period/2;
       Clock <= '1';
       wait for clk_period/2;   
   end process;

END;
```

When I simulate behavioral model, the ISIM pops up, but I see no changes on the Compare Flag. Here is the ss of the ISIM:
[image: ISIM SS]

What am I missing here? Why does'nt the Flag change?

My best regards.

Comment: You never initialize the counter by asserting the reset = '1' then back to '0' in your testbench. This would be readily apparent if you showed count or count_out in your waveform display.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I added another stimulus and can see the flag is changing. But, I guess it only becomes when value is equall to 0. I guess my counter does'nt work. How can I be sure if my count values chaning?

Comment: Add it to your waveform?  (And add a reset stimuli to your testbench). Also See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems, both in your testbench.

The first is that you never reset count in the counter, it will always be 'U's or 'X's (after you increment it).

The second is that the directly entity instantiation in the testbench is missing an association for the formal flag output to the actual flag signal:

```
begin

uut: 
    entity work.countcompare_src 
        port map (
            clock => clock,
            reset => reset,
            value => value,
            flag => flag
        );

proc: 
    process
    begin
        clock <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clock <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;  
        if now > 20 ns then
            wait;
        end if; 
    end process;

stimulus:
    process
    begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 1 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;
```

Fix those two things and you get:

[image: topleveltester_tb_fixed.png]

Comment: I see it now. Thank you :)